# why keycloak documentation suggest to not use spring boot adapter for war deployment

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, keycloak

[Here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter) in the key-cloak documentation, suggest not using the spring boot adapter if planning on deploying the application as a WAR. Right now, I already deployed the war in a tomcat using de spring boot adapter and another one with XML configuration suggested [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/securing_apps/index.html#_tomcat_adapter), but in both scenarios i successfully log in with the user configured in key-cloak and i have not seen any difference so far and the documentation doesn't explain why i shouldn't use this adapter.